# DMCA requirements for a chatroom

Tags: copyright, internet

Does hosting online chat require registering a dmca agent? I'm developing a multiplayer game and would include chat amongst friends and during gameplay. The chat messages are temporarily seen by the users while they are communicating and are not viewable after that.

I would assume that there can't be a dmca takedown notice for just temporary text in a chatroom. But I couldn't find anything in dmca section 512 that makes that clear. Does 512(a) apply to this?

According to 512(a)(3) only the sender must choose the recipients of the message and not the service provider. Does sending messages in a chatroom with random other people who joined count?

According to 512(a)(4) no copy should be maintained for long after the transfer of data.
What if I were to keep internal logs of messages that can't be accessed by anyone else? Would that change anything?

According to 512(a)(5) the material should not be modified as it trasmits through the system. What if I use profanity filters and similar software?

If 512(a) doesn't apply is there another way to avoid having to respond to dmca notices?

Answer (score -1):

Providing that aren't hosting content of someone else's creation or intellectual property. I cannot possible see an issue that could arise especially as you state it is text based therefore no media content could be hosted. Linking to DMCA content is not DMCA-able on your end only on the person(s) that are hosting it.

I would say that you are safe.

Comment: I think there is a lot of text that has copyrights.

Comment: Ya and there is nothing to stop the user from posting an entire short story over multiple messages. I really would have thought the fact that it's just temporarily viewable would be enough. Section 512(a) seems to be close to what I'm looking minus the few caveats I mentioned

Comment: Text can copyright protected but the likelihood of anything like that ever seeing a DMCA claim especially as you say will be only view-able for a short period of time. You can also create a disclaimer in the game with a DMCA form but if its not being stored anywhere there really isn't anything for you to enforce besides suspending the player.